# Magento 2 - How Can I Update Catalog Product Price Programmatically in Frontend and Add Product to Cart With New Price?

Tags: php, catalog, magento2.3, programmatically

I create one Module and make a custom form which is display in the catalog product view page.
when the customer change option from dropdown then the product price will change and also that updated price goto cart.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Use **checkout_cart_product_add_after**

Create a module and add events.xml in following path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

Add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                   
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">  
  <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">                       
     <observer name="setprice" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\SetPrice" />                                                                         
  </event>                                                            
</config>
```

then add observer in the below path

> Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\SetPrice.php

add below code in it

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;                                     
class SetPrice implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface          
{
 protected $_request;
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    array $data = []
 ) {
    $this->_request = $request;
 }

 public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 ) {
    $postdata = $this->_request->getPost();
    $priceoption = $postdata['input_name']; // say it select input field which you have
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
    $price = $priceoption; //set your price here
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
 }}
```

> $postdata['input_name']; this must be you select input name which you have in the form and in addition to above answer move your input fields to add to cart form fields.

To move your custom form inputs to **add to cart** form in below way.

Add the **catalog_product_view.xml**  then add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                             
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">                                                  
 <body>                                                 
    <referenceBlock name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::product/view/form.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>                                           
 </body>                                                        
</page>
```

then copy the form.phtml from vendor in order to **override** and move your input fields to there as per your requirements.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

To

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it work when product added to cart but first i want to update price in selecton of my custom options and after pass to cart

Comment: You want to update price in where in table or in PDP

Answer (score 2):

You could do that

At magento2 you can change quote item mean cart item price using below code:

```
$quoteItem = ( $quoteItem->getParentItem() ? $quoteItem->getParentItem() : $quoteItemitem );
$price = 150; //set your price here
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Most of the case, people using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` for set custom price to quote item.

I am not clear about your custom fields inside your custom form.I suggested that move all field of the custom field to Magento own add to cart form.
And then using `$quoteItem->getBuyRequest()` at observer like `sales_quote_item_set_product`, we can get all fields value which is posted during add to cart.

Suppose, you have field an input field name 'my_own_price` and  you want the value entered on this field will be set as price of this cart item.

```
<?php
/**
 * User: Amit Bera
 * Email: dev.amitbera@gmail.com
 */

namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class {Class} implements  ObserverInterface
{



    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        try{
            $buyRequest = $quoteItem->getBuyRequest();
            if (is_object($buyRequest)) {
                $buyRequestArray = $buyRequest->toArray();
                if (array_key_exists('my_own_price', $buyRequestArray)) {
                    $quoteItem = ( $quoteItem->getParentItem() ? $quoteItem->getParentItem() : $quoteItemitem );
                    $price = $buyRequestArray['my_own_price']; //set your price here
                    $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
                    $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                    $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true); 
                }

            }
        }catch (\Exception $exception)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can u give me more info about how can i update price of product in frontend when customer select the form option. in way of magento

Answer (score 2):

You Can achieve this using below code

Step 1 Create events.xml file in below path

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Save data in cart -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
            <observer name="namespace_modulename_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\CheckoutCartAddObserver" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

Step 2 : Create Observer file in below path

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Observer/CheckoutCartAddObserver.php

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;                                     
class CheckoutCartAddObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface          
{
 protected $_request;
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    array $data = []
 ) {
    $this->_request = $request;
 }

 public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 ) {
    $postdata = $this->_request->getPost();
    $priceoption = $postdata['your_dropdown_field_name']; // Your Drop down field name goes here 
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
    $price = $priceoption; //set your price here
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
 }}
```

Tell Me if above code is not work....!

@Prathap Gunasekaran There is no need to copy the form.phtml from vendor

Comment: Work Like Charm...!

Comment: @sanjay form.phtml  move his inputs to that form. So it requires and hope you understand what am trying to say.

Comment: @Prathap Gunasekaran I have append my custom form with add to cart form using jQuery so i don't need to copy the form.phtml from vendor

Comment: @BhaveshPrajapati You've mentioned as custom form which is why I've given such option to override.

Comment: because i want to append add to cart form 
and your way is proper but i have append my add to cart form using JQuery

var element = $('#fields').detach();
                     var form_class = $('#form_class').detach();
                     $('.box-tocart').prepend(element);
                     $('.box-tocart').prepend(form_class);

Comment: i am not use xml layout to override magento add to cart form 

i have alredy call my file to catalog product view page

Comment: No problem it helps you anyway :) magento way of doing is what I've explained, you can do that via jquery too . Thanks