# save custom value in proudct page to database table on add to cart clicked in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to save the custom options that are on the product page in the custom table on click of add to cart in magento2 
[image]
here you can see the options are displaying I want to save it in the database table on add to cart click and also show it in cart page

Comment: Is that the value comes from form data??

Comment: I have created the phtml file from that all are coming

Comment: Is that the input values are coming from form data. check it in network tab whether those inputs are coming in it when you add the product to cart

Comment: Try it like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264795/magento-2-how-can-i-update-catalog-product-price-programmatically-in-frontend/264803#264803

Comment: through that event, it will send in the database table ??

Comment: Magento 2 already save all posted `getBuyingRequest()` function of  Quote Item Object.

Comment: But i want to save it in my custom table in database on add to cart button click

Comment: Please don't post same type question again again

Answer (score -2):

You can use few events like

```
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
```

**And event details:**

> ```
>         $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
>             'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
>             ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
>         );
> ```

Or, you can use event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` .

At this can you can get `current cart item if/ quote item id`

> ```
>     $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
>         'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
>         ['quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product]
>     );
> ```

**At Second case, the observer code  is that**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\MagentoAnswer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfter implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $requestParams = $quoteItem->getBuyRequest();
        if ($requestParams instanceof \Magento\Framework\DataObject  && is_object($requestParams)) {
            // buyRequestArray is inddex
            $buyRequestArray = $requestParams->toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii amit can you please provide me whole code with folder struvturr i am new to magento so does now more about ut

Comment: after doing this add to cart button is not workin g

Comment: It means  addtocart post action is not hitting or you don't able to add to cart what is the issue?

Comment: i don't able to add to cart

Comment: its means add to cart button is not clicking?

Comment: it is clicking but item is not adding in cart